# Remove "page jumpyness" when moving a page element via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just as a little pre-info, I'm running a Volusion e-commerce site that has internal page HTML locked down, so I am unable to add any ID's or classes to internal page elements.

The default HTML provided by Volusion puts a table out of order for my design on my category pages. I have a bit of script that targets that table on my product category pages, and moves it. The problem is that the script is run after the page is loaded, causing a "jumping" effect as the table is moved via jquery.

The simple solution would be to hide the table first via css, and then have the jquery show the element after it has been moved, however, I am unaware of how to accomplish this.

Here is the moving script. It first detects if the user is on a category page via a URL check. It then finds the first child table inside the #content_area element, and moves it.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        if (location.pathname.indexOf("-s/") != -1) {
            var table_to_move = $("#content_area").find("table").first();
            $("#content_area").find("form").before(table_to_move).show();
            $('#jmenuhide').insertBefore('.refinement_price_section');
        }
        else {
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have tried targeting the element via css, and hiding it, and then re-showing it after the script has run. However, since I can only reference it through css selectors, and not an ID or class, the page will end up hiding the wrong table, as the table orders change when the script is run.

Anyone have any idea how I can smooth out this table movement? Thanks!

You can view this script in action at: http://www.yandasmusic.com/Folk-Instruments-s/1821.htm

Comment: I normally see this "jumpyness" when I call the script after the page has already been fully loaded, so you see the original page then the script is called to hide or move elements and thus the "jumpyness"

Comment: @SimplyCraig Exactly.

Comment: This is due to you editing the DOM, make sure you are only editing the DOM 1 time all at once, the more manipulation you do to it the more "jumpiness" you will experience.

Comment: If you cannot modify any HTML and can only use JavaScript after the fact, I am afraid you will be seeing some "jumpyness".  Not really sure that is avoidable.

Comment: Yea, I know that DOM manipulation after the page is loaded is a no-no. Unfortunately, I'm unaware of any other solution that will work on this platform. Is there some kind of "transition" effect that I can add to the jquery script that could smooth it out even a little?

Comment: You could look to simply hide both elements and move them into place and then redisplay them with `toggleFade()`.  That might look "cleaner"

Comment: Hmm, a good thought. There are three total tables stacked on top of each other. You're saying I should hide all three via css, have jquery make the move, and then show all three?

Comment: Yeah, if you can modify CSS and can effectively hide these elements until you have them in a place where you can display them, it will remove the "jumpyness" and allow you to gracefully bring them into view with a jQuery toggleFade effect.  (I mean there will still be a slight jump when you redisplay them, but I believe it will look "cleaner")

Comment: The reason you are seeing this "lag" is because you are doing multiple actions on the DOM instead get all the actions stored in variables and then do them all in one edit.

Comment: @abc123 Sorry, I'm not sure I follow. My jquery knowledge is limited :( How would I go about executing your recommendation?